# Is URL required when making an Image Sitemap

Tags: google, sitemap

The reason I ask, is I am making a script that searches a folder for images, so I don't necessarily know where they are used or the exact page. Example from google

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url> 
</urlset>
```

Is it possible to do and would google / other search engines read it properly still?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
            xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
      <url>
        <image:image>
          <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <image:image>
          <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
      </url> 
    </urlset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [sitemap.xsd](https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd) the `<loc>` is required. To be sure, check the result from [Google Test Sitemap](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list):[image: Google Test Sitemap Result]

Comment: For Image Search, it always requires an image & landing page pair. It needs the <loc> so that it knows which landing page to associate with the image.